# tokio Sender is not Sink

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I wonder how to `forward` one channel to another, except for writing a manual loop. It seemed pretty straightforward to imagine that both `tokio::mpsc::Sender` and `tokio::broadcast::Sender` might `impl Sink`. Stunningly, that's not just the case.

For instance, there is `tokio-stream` out there, but there is no `tokio-sink`. The reason is beyond me. Still ... Maybe I'm missing something or overlooked it.

Let's scrutinise the following code:

```
use tokio::sync::broadcast;
use tokio_stream::wrappers::BroadcastStream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
        let (mut tx0, mut rx0) = broadcast::channel::<u32>(10);
        let (mut tx1, mut rx1) = broadcast::channel::<u32>(10);
        tokio::task::spawn(async move {
            BroadcastStream::new(rx0).forward(tx1).await;
        });
        tx0.send(1);
        println!("{:?}", rx1.recv().await);
}
```

it would result with an error:

```
the trait `futures::Sink<u32>` is not implemented for `tokio::sync::broadcast::Sender<u32>
```

How it should be done properly?

Answer (score 1):

The mpsc channel has a `Sink` implementation available as [`tokio_util::sync::PollSender`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/sync/struct.PollSender.html). There is currently no `Sink` implementation for the broadcast channel.

Currently, the idiomatic way to forward to a broadcast channel is to use a loop.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy enough to implement the forwarding yourself:

```rust
use tokio::sync::broadcast::{self, error::RecvError};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx0, mut rx0) = broadcast::channel(10);
    let (tx1, mut rx1) = broadcast::channel(10);
    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            match rx0.recv().await {
                Ok(v) => _ = tx1.send(v),
                Err(RecvError::Closed) => break,
                Err(RecvError::Lagged(_)) => continue,
            }
        }
    });
    tx0.send(1_u32).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", rx1.recv().await);
}
```

Comment: The question was *except for writing a manual loop*.